# Helicon Isapi rewrite - can't get urls to be case insensitive

Tags: url-rewriting, mod-rewrite, isapi

Running Helicon Isapi rewrite to make overly long coldfusion CMS generated urls 'friendly'. Works very well and we've been using it for several years both with direct rewrites and regex.

I cannot get it to treat urls case insensitively.

The following rule is an example:

```
RewriteRule /scriptcontent/h1n1/h1n1submission.cfm\?section=Human_swine_H1N1_influenza    http\://www.racgp.org.au/h1n1influenza/feedback [I,RP]

RewriteRule /h1n1influenza\/feedback? /scriptcontent/h1n1/h1n1submission.cfm\?section=Human_swine_H1N1_influenza
```

I thought the [I] flag should make isapi ignore case but www.racgp.org.au/h1n1influenza/feedback works where www.racgp.org.au/H1N1influenza/feedback doesn't.

I can get around it by making another rule for upper case and redirecting to the lowercase url but would rather have a setup that works for all urls regardless of case.

Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

I think the [I] flag applies to the [IIRF](http://iirf.codeplex.com) filter .
For Helicon maybe you want [NC]  (menmonic "**N**ot **C**ase sensitive")

Comment: Tried NC but get an error in the error log:

    Line 5119: Unrecognized string: RewriteRule /scriptcontent/h1n1/h1n1submission.cfm\?section=Human_swine_H1N1_influenza http\://www.racgp.org.au/h1n1influenza/feedback [NC,RP]

RewriteRule /h1n1influenza\/feedback? /scriptcontent/h1n1/h1n1submission.cfm\?section=Human_swine_H1N1_influenza [NC]

Comment: ??  That is surprising.  IS it the commercial or free version of Helicon?  I don't know the product, but maybe there is a difference in the features supported by the different variants.   Either the [I] or the [NV} would work in IIRF.

Comment: Its the commercial version, although I don't think the most recent. All the doc files use [I] but I can never get this to work. Maybe the problem is elsewhere?

Comment: Is there some way to check the success or failure of parsing the INI file?  In IIRF there's a HTTP status page that the filter gives you, which tells you if there were errors or warnings with the rules.

Comment: Yes, there is a httpd.parse.errors file - if I use [I] it does not log anything wrong. When I used [NC] I got 'unrecognized string' (the error in my first comment above.

Comment: If you are using ISAPI-Rewrite2, the flag is [I], if it's ISAPI-Rewrite3, the flag is [NC]. Could you specify hte exact version and build.

Comment: This solution worked for me. I am using the 64-bit Helicon Version 3 and [NC].